# Define metric space from normed linear space without using the norm

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

(If this question may expose some fundamental misunderstanding about normed linear spaces and metric spaces, I appreciate any corrections to these misconceptions in lieu of answering the question directly.)

I understand that if we have a normed linear space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$, it is also a metric space with the metric $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. Is it reasonable/possible/sensible to define a metric space from $X$ without using the norm as the metric? e.g. could it make sense to define a metric space from the normed linear space by equipping it with the discrete metric instead?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to define the discrete metric on *any* set. But why would you do that on a real vector space $V$? Then, for instance, if you take $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$, the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&V\\\lambda&\mapsto&\lambda v\end{array}$$will not be continuous.

Comment: I suppose my question should have been, "why do we say that 'a normed linear space is a metric space' with the *specific* metric $d(x,y)=||x-y||$?" It seems that we're arbitrarily creating a metric on the original vector space (we just happen to be choosing one that's very reasonable). So, if we're taking a normed vector space and assigning an arbitrary metric to it to make it a metric space, what makes it special? E.g. why can't we extend this same argument to conclude that 'any set is a metric space?'

Comment: On any normed vector space you define, as you wrote, $d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert$. How do you do the same thing on an arbitrary set?

Comment: The "argument" would be that since we're defining $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ arbitrarily, we can simply pick another metric e.g. $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise. This is a weird choice to make, but I can't see the formal reason we aren't allowed to do it. 

Continuing with this reasoning, since we're imposing the discrete metric $d(x,y)$ on the normed linear space, we can similarly impose the discrete metric onto any set and conclude it's a metric space.

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But then, when we are dealing with a vector space, we get a distance that has no relation whatsoever with the vector space structure. And I must say that I think that it is rather strange that you find arbitrary the choice of taking $d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert$. The norm is already there and the map $(x,y)\mapsto\lVert x-y\rVert$ is a distance!